# Why link tables in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Such a good day, everyone is well, the question is the following.

I think a couple of tables in mysql, I sometimes get data from both research I come across the typical "link two tables", "make two queries to two tables", but this has me confused.

That is, if we have two tables, as follows:

```
Tabla1
| id |  nick  |  
|-------------
| 1 | admin|   

tabla2
| id_post | content | autor |
|---------------------------------
|   100     | asdasd |   1      |
```

Why relate from mysql, but when you query you can do:

```
select tabla1.nick, tabla2.* from tabla1, tabla2, where id="1" and tabla2.autor = tabla1.id
```

**What is the difference between the two?, Or what is the benefit to having one or the other?**

Comment: what do you mean, "relate from mysql"? That's the whole point of a RELATIONAL database... related tables getting joined in queries... perhaps you're actually asking about `JOIN` syntax, instead of the oldschool version you're using?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, the difference between what and what? A "link" (as you put it) in MySQL (like in every relational database) is formed by storing the primary key of one table in a column of another table, as a foreign key. The rows are "related" by the values stored in the columns. As in your example, the `autor` column in `Tabla2` appears to be a foreign key referencing `Tabla1.id`. The query in your question is performing a JOIN operation, relating rows in tabla2 to rows in tabla1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking about constraints, why actually make column X on table A refer to column Y on table B, when you can just join the two tables in a SELECT query?

This is to enforce referential integrity, to reduce redundancy, etc. Doing so makes the data itself reliable so that when you use joins in your SELECT statement, they work as they should.

If you had an ASSIGNMENTS and a SUPERVISORS table, for instance, and each assignment is always assigned to a supervisor on a supervisors table, a foreign key constraint between the supervisor field on ASSIGNMENTS and SUPERVISORS will ensure that happens. It also gives you flexibility as to what should occur if the supervisor value changes on one table (should it be restricted? should the change be carried through to the other table? etc.)

Without the relationship being defined, an assignment might be assigned to a supervisor who does not even exist. And then the results of your SELECT statements won't be all that reliable...

Comment: +1. Note that only a subset of the MySQL storage engines actually enforce referential integrity. InnoDB enforces referential integrity, but MyISAM does not. (MyISAM accepts syntax to define foreign keys,  but it does not actually enforce the defined foreign key constraints.)